# Filter out rows based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe:

```
   | from id | from group | to id | to group   |
   |    1    |      A     |   3   |      B     |
   |    4    |      B     |   4   |      X     | 
   |    5    |      F     |   5   |      J     |
   |    2    |      B     |   3   |      A     |
```

Looking at the 'from group' and 'to group' column. I want to remove rows where 'A and B' AND 'F and J' are present in both columns.

Expected output:

```
        | from id | from group | to id | to group   |
        |    4    |      B     |   4   |      X     |
```

I am looking for a solution that is flexible. Meaning if a 3rd condition was added, it would not change

Answer (score -1):

Supposing that you're using `pandas` try something like:

```
df.loc[~((df['from group'].isin(['A','B'])) & (df['to group'].isin(['A','B'])))]
```

The `~` in front of the first parenthesis will define a negation of the coming filter

Answer (score -1):

Looks long but very simple

```
df.query("not ((`from group` == 'A' and `to group` == 'B') or (`from group` == 'B' and `to group` == 'A') or (`from group` == 'F' and `to group` == 'J') or (`from group` == 'J' and `to group` == 'F'))")
```

-=- EDIT -=-

Here's a more complicated but more scalable solution.
just define `l1` as the pairs you want to exclude

```
l1 = [['A', 'B'], ['F', 'J']]
l2 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([itertools.permutations(i, r=2) for i in l1]))


df[[j not in l2 for j in list(zip(df['from group'], df['to group']))]]
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution that can work on a larger dataset with up to 10 different conditions. So a more flexible solution.

Comment: New solution provided